# Howto fit a smoothed line in plotly with date as x axis in an RShiny dash?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Running into some issues trying to implement this. Pretty much I have a dataset set with two relevant features, a value and a date (YYYY-MM-DD). Each date has many values and I want to fit a polynomial LOB through the mean (or median) of the scatterplot of each date values. The dates are stored as date objects and values are stored as floats. I'm also doing it on an RShiny dashboard.

I've tried this, with no luck.

```
    output$plot<- renderPlotly({
        ggplot(df(), aes(x = date, y = value,
                        text = paste('Headline: ', headline, '\n Author: ', author, '\n value: ', value))) + 
        geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) + 
        ggtitle('Overall Value') +
        ylim(-1, 1) +   
        stat_smooth()

    })
```

All I get is some output, but no line rendering on the graph.

```
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

I've tried a few other ways, but no luck. Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to use `ggplotly`, try `p <- ggplot(...); ggplotly(p)`

Comment: That doesn't work, the has always plot rendered fine. Its the line of best fit that isn't fitting.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `stat_smooth` didn't like the `text` in the `aes`, so I had to play around a bit with the mappings. Please be aware that using `ylim` instead of `coord_cartesian` can change the calculation of `stat_smooth`.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

headline = "test"
author = "starja"
value = "none"

set.seed(8)
test_data <- data.frame(date = rep(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2003/1/1"), by = "quarter"), each = 3),
                        value = rnorm(39))

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("test_plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test_plot<- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot() + 
      geom_point(data = test_data, mapping = aes(x = date, y = value,
                                text = paste('Headline: ', headline, '\n Author: ', author, '\n value: ', value)), na.rm = TRUE) + 
      ggtitle('Overall Value') +
      ylim(c(-1, 1)) +
      stat_smooth(aes(x = date, y = value), data = test_data)
    
    ggplotly(p)
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```